# DB Query or rule engine query to fetch best match of a given fileds

Tags: mysql, mongodb, drools, rule-engine

I have some mobile inventory table like below.

```
OSType   DeviceType  Make     year     Country    Value 
(attr1)   (attr2)   (attr3)   (attr4)  (attr5)   (result)
BADA        Galaxy   Samsung   2014     IN        100
Android     null     Samsung   2015     China     150
null        J7       Samsung   2018     IN        80
Android     Note10   Samsung   2019     null      500 
Android     Note10   Samsung   2019     null      500
IOS         I7       APPLE     null     USA       500 
IOS         null     null      2019     ALL       1000
```

I have to write a rule engine kind of query to find out best match  for a below kind of combination

**First query If all given params  are matched**

```
if the query input is  OStype=BADA,DeviceType=Galaxy, Make=Samsung, year=2014 Country=IN
```

Since it is a direct query then I can write straight query

**second query If all given params also have to be checked with null values**

if the query   OStype=Android,DeviceType=Note10, Make=Samsung, year=2019 Country=IN

then I should return 500 (because as per our business requirement if the table contains null or ALL I have to consider that field as a valid)

```
db.inventory.find( {
    $and : [
        { $or : [ { OStype : Android }, { OStype : null } ] },
        { $or : [ { DeviceType : Note10 }, { DeviceType : null } ] },
        { $or : [ { Make : Samsung }, { Make : null } ] },
        { $or : [ { year : 2019 }, { year : null } ] },
        { $or : [ { Country : IN }, { Country : null } ] }
    ]
} )

 This query ends up with returning more than one value because I have to consider **null** as per business requirement
```

So how to rune this query match only one ?

**Third kind of query is to return best match:**

if the query  is OStype=Android,DeviceType=J7, Make=Samsung, year=2019 Country=IN 
In this case year is not matching but still I have to return value 80 to the user with best matching description.

help how to handle null cases and how to write a query to find best match would help lot.

I tried droole rule engine but it does not for my requirement ..

Comment: I assume `Make, year` and `value` columns will not have NULL?

Comment: Value will not have null .. Other input param can be null.. in my business requirement doc no where explicitly mentioned that it can not be null, so I need to come with logic assuming input params can be null.

Comment: So you're attempting this on MongoDB only or do you need MySQL solution as well?

Comment: I need on mongodb... even if the solution is mysql I can try to re-write that for mongodb

Comment: Actually I noticed that `make` & `year` have NULL. Maybe you can clarify more on the search term, on which columns that the value won't consider NULL. For example your third condition; year is not matching we can add a few `OR` to satisfy the requirement but what if all of the other values are not match? I assume it shouldn't be like that. There's at least 1 must have condition like `make= ...` or `devicetype=... ` must always have something.

Comment: in third condition I need to throw exception or return null incase of no match . Second case is also important how to write query to consider both null or value case. The query I wrote return many matching value due to null or value compare